# How to set the button of fragment to close the activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have listed 3 fragments in my CustomActivity and set a button in the third fragment. I want to finish my CustomActivity by setting the setOnClickListener in CustomActivity using the button set in the third fragment. But I get the error message of: `kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException`. Please help me to remove this error.

The button of third fragment is `android:id="@+id/returnButton"`

This is CustomActivity code.

```
class CustomActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom)

        val fragmentList = arrayListOf<Fragment>(
            TutorialFragment(),
            TutorialFragment2(),
            TutorialFragment3()
        )

        val adapter = MyAdapter(supportFragmentManager, fragmentList)
        viewPager.adapter = adapter



        val button : Button = findViewById(R.id.returnButton)!!
        button.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(this,CustomActivity::class.java)
                this.finish()
            }
```

Comment: Always try to add error message, that way you can get answer much quickly

Comment: Unrelated, but please see #3 in https://proandroiddev.com/the-seven-actually-10-cardinal-sins-of-android-development-491d2f64c8e0

Answer (score 2):

The thing you are doing wrong is accessing the view of the fragment i.e button and setting the listener in the Activity, which is wrong.

Here if you want to finish the activity from button click from fragment you can directly set the listener inside `onViewCreated()` method of the `TutorialFragment`.

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    returnButton.setOnClickListener {
        activity?.finish()
    }
}
```

Also, please avoid using `!!` in your code.
The not-null assertion operator (!!) converts any value to a non-null type and throws an exception if the value is null.
Thus, if you want an NPE, you can have it, but you have to ask for it explicitly, and it does not appear out of the blue.

Answer (score 0):

In the Fragment

```
activity?.let{
it.finish()
}
```